# CMake: Not Found Tcmalloc: Tcmalloc_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, cmake

I am trying to execute CMake in a C++ project which uses Tcmalloc.

The vm is new and I tried to install first

```
sudo apt-get install libgoogle-perftools-dev
```

Which upon other things it installed libtcmalloc-minimal4

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
The following additional packages will be installed:
   libgoogle-perftools4 liblzma-dev libtcmalloc-minimal4
   libtcmalloc-minimal4 (2.5-2.2ubuntu3) ... 
Setting up
```

But cmake still produces the following warning:

```
 -- Not Found Tcmalloc: Tcmalloc_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

I also executed

```
dpkg -l | grep tcmalloc

 ii  libtcmalloc-minimal4      2.5-2.2ubuntu3      amd64      efficient thread-caching malloc
```

xUbuntu version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Do I miss any other step or install any other package? Do I have to create any symbolic link in `/usr/lib`?

Comment: Have you tried `cmake` with the extra options such as `cmake -DHPX_WITH_MALLOC=system` as shown [here](https://github.com/STEllAR-GROUP/hpx/issues/2524)? Also please share which version of Ubuntu is this.